# How send value from ini file to bs4 find? (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, configparser

How i can send value from ini file to BeautifulSoup.find()?

settings.ini:

```
   [tpk]
      pattern = 'h2'
```

main.py:

```
   import configparser
   config = configparser.ConfigParser()
   config.read('settings.ini')
   ...
   result = soup.find(config['tpk']['pattern']).text
   print(result)
```

This solution not working..
Thank You and sorry for my English

Comment: Have you tried printing `config['tpk']['pattern']` first, to see if it is what it should be?

Comment: are you sure there's an `h2`  in your soup?

Answer (score 1):

So basically the problem lays within your settings.ini. You can't store h2 as 'h2' because when you try to import it into your python code it gets imported as "'h2'" which does not exist on the website.
You need to store it as:

```
[tpk]
pattern = h2
```

sample code

```py
import requests
import configparser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "http://www.techonthenet.com/html/elements/h2_tag.php"
page = requests.get(URL)

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("settings.ini")
pattern = config.get("tpk", "pattern")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
results = soup.find(pattern)

print(results.prettify())
```

you can test it for yourself.